# Need a fairly complex regex for a simple text document

Tags: php, regex, perl

I'd prefer the answer to be either in php or perl since I have those easily at my disposal

The format of the file is as follows:

```
Name : ...
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)
Name : ...                         <--- These are the lines I need
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)     <--- 
<span style='color:red;'>FAILED to INSERT ...</span>
Name : ...
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)
...
```

The lines that are followed by the "FAILED to INSERT" span are the ones I'm interested in.
I'd like to remove all successful inserts and leave just the Name: and INSERT INTO parts of the lines that failed.

The "Name:" and "INSERT INTO..." parts are not necessarily on a single line.

This is my pseudo pattern that I think I need to match:

```
(/Name:/)(any character)(/INSERT INTO/)(anything but not /Name:/)(/FAILED to INSERT/)
```

Which would leave me with

```
Name: ...
INSERT INTO ...
<span ...> FAILED to INSERT
```

For each failed insert

I'm familiar with some regex basics, but could use some help with this one.
How might I do that in either perl or php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [Frits van Campen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/722762/frits-van-campen), regex can only be part of the solution, not the whole solution if you want to solve that quickly. I used some other logic as in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10146884), because it was not fully correct:

```
$file = new SPLFileObject("strangefile.txt");

foreach($file as $line)
{
    if (isset($buffer) && substr($line, 0, 25) === "<span style='color:red;'>") {
        echo $buffer . $line;
        unset($buffer);
        continue;
    }

    if (substr($line, 0, 5) === "Name:") {
        $buffer = '';
    }
    isset($buffer) && $buffer .= $line;
}
```

Comment: this seems more plausible, but I'm not sure I follow exactly. the foreach loop splits the document on a line by line basis correct? How can we retrieve a previous line if we've already gone on to the next one?

Comment: @pclem12: Correct, line-by-line. `$buffer` stores all lines since the last `Name:`, that's what it is used for.

Comment: @hakre - +1 I had the same idea, but don't know much php.  I like your use of $buffer.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this is an appropriate task for a regex. It is clearer to read through the file and accumulate the information you require line by line.

This is a Perl solution that uses the sample data you provided.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $info;

while (<DATA>) {
  $info = '' if /Name :/;
  $info .= $_;
  print $info if /FAILED to INSERT/;
}

__DATA__

Name : ...
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)
Name : ...                         <--- These are the lines I need
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)     <--- 
<span style='color:red;'>FAILED to INSERT ...</span>
Name : ...
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)
...
```

**output**

```
Name : ...                         <--- These are the lines I need
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)     <--- 
<span style='color:red;'>FAILED to INSERT ...</span>
```

I hope it's clear how to read the data from a file instead. If you pass the file name on the command line then you can just change the loop to `while (<>) { ... }`.

---

**Edit**

For a one-line command solution, how about this

```
perl -0777 -ne"/FAILED to INSERT/ and print for split /(?=Name :)/" myfile
```

**output**

```
Name : ...                         <--- These are the lines I need
INSERT INTO (...) Values (...)     <---
<span style='color:red;'>FAILED to INSERT ...</span>
```

Comment: thank you, this looks like a good solution and is much more intuitive. I'll give it a whirl

Answer (score 3):

I believe @FritsvanCampen is on the right track.  Instead of using a regular expression, it would be just as easy to loop through the entire file line by line.  Here's a slightly modified version using a multi-dimensional array.  (FYI, I don't really know php, so it may need a tweak or two).

```
$handle = fopen("strangefile.txt", "r");

$names = array();
$name = array();
while($line = fgets($handle)) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 5) === "Name:") {
      // start a new name array
      $name = array($line);
    }
    else
    {
      // append to existing name array
      $name[] = $line;

      // check to see if the current name array is type 'error'
      if (substr($line, 0, 31) === "<span style='color:red;'>FAILED to INSERT") {
        $names[] = $name;
      }
    }
}
var_dump($names);
```

Answer (score 2):

Regexps are a pain, how about something like this?

```
$handle = fopen("strangefile.txt", "r");

$collect = true;
$names = array();
while($line = fgets($handle)) {
    if (substr($line, 0, 31) === "<span style='color:red;'>FAILED to INSERT") {
        $collect = false;
    } else if ($collect && substr($line, 0, 5) === "Name:") {
        $names[] = $line;
    }
}
var_dump($names);
```

Comment: That would work if the lines I wanted were after the error line, however the lines I want precede the line with the <span>. So I don't know its an error until I've already processed the relevant lines if I'm using a line by line solution

Comment: That's what it does .. it doesn't start collecting until it's seen `"<span style='color:red;'>FAILED to INSERT"` at the beginning of a line.

Comment: if you have three lines, the first is the Name: line, the second is the INSERT INTO line and the third is the <span>, I need the first two lines, after I see that the third is that span. With you method, $line would be line 1, then line 2, then $start would be true on line 3. Then on the next line (line 4) it would take the entire line

Comment: The logic is a bit inverted, however principally it's solveable that way, compare with [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10147009/367456) which is similar.

Comment: Oh, well in that case invert the check on `$start`, stop collecting once you've seen the line that signals error lines. I've updated the code.

Comment: @FritsvanCampen: I understand it: If you encounter a line with `<span>error`, give all lines since the last `Name:` (incl.). And not collection all names until error.

Comment: yes, sorry guys, I had trouble seeing it until I saw it in a slightly different syntax. All three of these solutions are essentially the same logic